# Plot Signal on price closing above keltner channel

Tags: pine-script, trading

Hello I am playing around with Keltner channels and signals

I want to

- plot a triangle signal when a candle closes above the upper boundary of the channel
- plot a triangle signal when a candle closes below the lower boundary of the channel
- plot no triangles if a candle closes in between the boundaries of the channel

I'm currently using the ta.crossover function to identify when the candle is above or below the boundaries of the channel.

Made sure to say `close, upper`, but it's not really working well as signals are firing whenever price crosses the boundary rather than only when it closes above / below the boundary. I'm using the

[alerts firing whenever price crosses the boundary rather than closing above or below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlPtg.jpg)

Full script below and any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
//@version=5

indicator(title='KC', shorttitle='KC', overlay=true, timeframe='')

offset = input.float(1.1, step=.1)
useTrueRange = input(true)
length = input.int(200, minval=1)
mult = input.float(1, step=.1)
src = input(close, title='Source')

ma = ta.ema(src, length)
range_1 = useTrueRange ? ta.tr : high - low
rangema = ta.ema(range_1, length)
upper = ma + rangema * mult
lower = ma - rangema * mult
c = color.gray


// BASIS, UPPER, LOWER

u = plot(upper, color=color.new(c, 0), title='Upper')

plot(ma, color=color.new(c, 0), title='Basis')

l = plot(lower, color=color.new(c, 0), title='Lower')

fill(u, l, color.new(c, 90))


// TRIANGLES

long = ta.crossover(close, upper)
plotshape(long, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.lime, 0), editable=true, size=size.tiny)

short = ta.crossover(close, lower)
plotshape(short, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.red, 0), editable=true, size=size.tiny)
```